# Reading from one file and writing into another in Python

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that finds certain lines of text in a file and writes them to another file to get rid of all the annoying text in between (it's a .vmg file). Through my skills of python and googleing I have writen the following program.

```
with open("filein.txt") as f:
    with open("fileout.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if "telephone number" in line:
                f1.write(line)
            if "telephone number" and "X-BOX" in line:
                f1.write(line)
            if "Subject" in line:
                f1.write(line)
```

The program is working fine, but for the "subject" I want to tell the program to write not just the single line of text where the keyword "subject" is, but until it reaches a certain keyword (in my case that is "END:VBODY"). What should I do?

Comment: Please leave things like "I'm new to Stack Overflow..." out of your question. I think your question was put together well, so you didn't really need it. If your question wasn't phrased well, that statement certainly wouldn't stop your question from being downvoted or closed. Welcome to the community!

Comment: Also, I have a couple of code notes for you: your snippet would be a bit cleaner if you opened both files in one statement and used more descriptive variable names: `with open("filein.txt") as f_in, open("fileout.txt", "w") as f_out:`

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but you can just use a flag to indicate whether or not the cursor is in between the Subject and END:VBODY::

```
with open("filein.txt") as f:
    with open("fileout.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if in_subject:
                f1.write(line)
                if "END:VBODY" in line:
                    in_subject = False
            else:
                if "telephone number" in line:
                    f1.write(line)
                if "telephone number" and "X-BOX" in line:
                    f1.write(line)
                if "Subject" in line:
                    in_subject = True
                    f1.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need this one particular case, you can walk away with simple state variable. Something like this:

```
inside_subject = False
with open("fileout.txt", "w") as out:
    for line in open("filein.txt", "r"):
        if inside_subject:
            if not "END:VBODY" in line:
                print line
            else:
                inside_subject = False
        else:
            if "telephone number" in line:
                out.write(line)
            elif "telephone number" in line and "X-BOX" in line: # will never match this though
                out.write(line)
            elif "Subject" in line:
                out.write(line)
                inside_subject = True
```

Though if you'll have more conditions, consider using some state machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "Subject" in line:
    f1.write(line[:line.index("END:VBODY")])
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to write not just part of the current line but the current line plus additional lines until finding the end marker.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working solution just by adding a while loop under the `if "Subject" in line` condition.

```
with open("filein.txt") as f:
    with open("fileout.txt", "w") as f1:
        for line in f:
            if "telephone number" in line:
                f1.write(line)
            if "telephone number" and "X-BOX" in line:
                f1.write(line)
            if "Subject" in line:
                f1.write(line)

                # new code added here
                while 'END:VBODY' not in line:
                    line = f.next()
                    f1.write(line)
```

Comment: You can use `with open("filein.txt") as f, open("fileout.txt", "w") as f1:` in a single line.